# For loop and text replacement

Tags: batch-file

Sorry for the noob question, I need to bulk replace strings taken from a list of files, I have found in the internet that the syntax is :
%variable:StrToFind=NewStr%

```
FOR %%f IN (*.wav) DO (
    set "el = %%f"
    echo %el%
    echo %%f
    echo %%f:wav=mp3%
)
```

The output is, for file A.wav:

- ECHO Disabled
- A.wav
- A.wav:wav=mp3

Obviously my intent is to produce A.mp3
What am I missing?

Comment: `FOR %%f IN (*.wav) DO echo %%~nf.mp3`

Comment: I wish I understand what it means... bit it works thank you very much

Comment: Type `for /?` into a command prompt window and read the help very carefully...